# Why flex string is NOT supporting unicode 0?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3

When I am trying to convert bytes to characters, flex stops conversion if it encounters unicoder number 0 (NUL). Why is it so? Flex is able to convert 1-256 unicode numbers except 0.
In the following example, Alert window does NOT display any text, because parameters started with 0 while forming the string message from unicode numbers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application name="Alert" xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" creationComplete="init();">
    <s:controlBarContent>
        <s:Button id="btn"
                  label="Show alert"
                  click="init();"/>
    </s:controlBarContent>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            protected function init():void {
                // if string message value is String.fromCharCode(78,0);, then Alert displays as N
                //Here, since message starts with unicode character 0, Alert displays nothing. 
                //Flex string is getting stopped if it encounters unicode 0, why is it so? 
                //but flex string supports other contorl ascii characters except NUL (0)
                var message:String=String.fromCharCode(0, 78, 1);
                Alert.show(message, "", Alert.YES | Alert.NO | Alert.OK | Alert.CANCEL);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>    
</s:Application>
```

I am not sure why flex is not able to convert unicode 0 character? 
Temporarily, I am converting them to 32 (empty space) if it is 0. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Good question!. I try it on my Flash Builder 4.6.

As i Know is String.fromCharCode(num),num depend from [keycode](http://www.expandinghead.net/keycode.html)

if your get the num begin at 1~Max and it not include in keycode list,

it will return whitespace. But if the num is 0,fromCharCode will return undefined ref.

But you cloud get string length from this string array:

{undefined,h}.length = 2

{undefined,h} make to string = undefined. remember it as X.

i will show you the Math

`h+X = h+undefined.`

you could try this:

```
var str:String =  String.fromCharCode(0,104);
var str1:String =  String.fromCharCode(1,104);
var str2:String =  String.fromCharCode(104,0,104);
Alert.show(str);
Alert.show(str.length.toString());
Alert.show(str1);
Alert.show(str1.length.toString());
Alert.show(str2);
Alert.show(str2.length.toString());
```

You will see str2 show you something different.
{h,undefined,h}.length = 3

for each this for string ref will be:

h+X = h+undefined.

I Guess it's reason is `String.fromCharCode` Function don't catch

```
if(codenum == 0){return whitespace}
```

It may use as switch or for or others way begin the code num at 1.

Answer (score 0):

C strings are terminated by a `null` byte `\0` character.

Similar to C, I believe ActionScript interprets this as a [null terminated string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).

Answer (score 0):

Because 0 byte is not actually a string char. If you are working with binary data keep it in [ByteArray](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html)